# Is there a way that I could export my defaultNavigationOptions in a separate component?

Tags: javascript, react-native, react-navigation, bottomnavigationview

I use the same code on multiples places, for each Screen I have a BottomTabNavigator using react-navigation v3.0.

The issue is that I need to pass props from my parent component to a child component through my TabNigator (which works currently), reason why I'm creating a separate  TabNavigator for each screen.

Is there a way that I could optimize my code? maybe exporting my TabNavigator?

```
import Chrono from "../../../assets/tools/Chrono"
import Session from "./Session"
import Resultats from "./Resultats"
```

```
constructor(props) {
        super(props)
        this.state = {
            myPath: 'DeveloppeCouche',
        }
        this.AppContainer = createAppContainer(this.TabNavigator)
    }
```

```
TabNavigator = createBottomTabNavigator({
        MainPage, // current page with some text and pictures of the exercice
        Chrono,
        Session: { screen: () => <Session myPath={this.state.myPath} /> },
        Resultats: { screen: () => < Resultats myPath={this.state.myPath} /> }
    }, {
            defaultNavigationOptions: ({ navigation }) => ({
                tabBarIcon: ({ tintColor }) => {
                    const { routeName } = navigation.state;
                    let IconComponent = Ionicons;
                    let iconName;
                    if (routeName === 'MainPage') {
                        iconName = 'md-home';
                    } else if (routeName === 'Chrono') {
                        iconName = 'md-time';
                    } else if (routeName === 'Session') {
                        iconName = 'md-save';
                    } else if (routeName === 'Resultats') {
                        iconName = 'md-analytics';
                    }
                    return <IconComponent name={iconName} size={25} color={tintColor} />;
                },
            }),
            tabBarOptions: {
                activeTintColor: 'red',
                inactiveTintColor: 'gray',
            },
        })
```

I'm building a fitness app for my thesis. There are a lot of different exercises in my app and this code is re-used a lot. Any clues?

Comment: Do you mean you have the same TabNavigator component with same screens (MainPage, Chrono, Session etc.)separately defined in each of the screens?

Comment: Not the same MainPage, i should rename it CurrentPage. but the other pages remain the same, the path "myPath" that i pass to Session & Resultats is defined on the CurrentPage(MainPage), chrono is a Chronometer that remain the same everywhere it's implemented

Comment: You shoudn't have to define TabNavigator component in each of the screens. The bottom tab bar will remain visible in all screens by default, if that's what you want.

Define only a single navigator as you App container and define all the required screens as routes in it

Comment: I'll give it a try, Thank you @NishantNair .